# One liner: Find if string is in list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I am looking for a boolean one-liner to see if a specific substring is in a list of strings. So that I can use it in something like

```
if( (condition1) and (condition2) and (python_one_liner) ):
  # Do some things here
```

This would hopefully replace something like:

```
if( (condition1) and (condition2) ):
  Condtion3 = False
  for str in list_of_strings:
    if( mystr in str ):
    Condition3 = True

  if( Condition3 ):
    # Do some things here
```

An obvious approach is to simply write a function and evaluate that function in the initial `if` statement. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) together with a generator expression:

```
if condition1 and condition2 and any(mystr in s for s in list_of_strings):
```

This is more efficient than your version in that only enough `s` values from `list_of_strings` are tested until a first `True` value is found.

If you needed to also know *what* string matched, you can get the first such string with:

```
match = next((s for s in list_of_strings if mystr in s), None)
if condition1 and condition2 and match:
```

where the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) iterates over the generator expression to the first match and returns that, or returns `None` if there are no matching strings.

Comment: I agree.  I would change from a list of strings to a set of strings to make the lookups faster.

Comment: @bgm387: no, that won't work as this is about *containment in the individual strings*.

Comment: Thanks - this does exactly what I want. Bonus points -> is there any way to do this evaluation and then save the results for reference in the conditional statement?

Comment: @Laurbert515: you mean as a function or as a static result? `any()` returns a boolean, you can just do `result = any(....)` to store the outcome for later use.

Comment: When the if statement is true, I will need to find the exact line in `list_of_strings` again and then do some processing. Is there a way to grab the appropriate line in the same evaluation?

Comment: @Laurbert515: then use `next((s for s in list_of_strings if mystr in s), None)` to get the first such `s`, or `None` if there is no such matching string.